# How long can Daleks and Davros live?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

Do Daleks live forever, barring any chance the Doctor gets to destroy them?

Giving Davros an age is going to be difficult, if only because he was left for dead at the end of *Genesis of the Daleks* but was resurrected in *Destiny of the Daleks*. As well, there are issues if he is presumably able to time travel. As well, it may be that his life support system is keeping him alive longer than usual. But as a Kaled, is there any indication of how old he is and what his life span is?

Comment: How are you reckoning time? A Dalek could appear to live forever by time travel.

Comment: Hmmmm .... yes, and I'm aware that the Doctor has stated when in the TARDIS they are in a state of temporal grace where "In a sense, ..., we don't exist while we're in here" which may suggest they don't age. This presumably applies to the Daleks when they are time travelling in their machines. But outside of a time machine they have a "body clock" and is there a limit to how many clicks on the clock they have?

Comment: @Durakken In their own timeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Witch's Familiar also pointed out that the Dalek sewer/graveyard is full of Daleks that have reduced to amorphic plasma, yet still lived. Too full of hate to even let themselves die. So it's possible the life span of the Kaled mutant IN the Dalek travel machine could be impossibly long, just not in the same exact form. So they age in the Dalek machine, eventually becoming too useless to control the machine, but do not die.

Davros is still humanoid, and is kept alive by the systems in his chair. He also (apparently) survive outside his chair for limited periods of time - my money's on VERY limited. Also, the "centuries" The Doctor speaks COULD only refer to the time Davros was awake and responsive - he's spent many many years in various states of suspension. he has, by definition, lived as long as the Daleks have existed.  Depending on how you calculate that time, and assuming he hasn't engaged in any temporal shifts, he may have lived for millennia.

Answer (score 3):

### Unknown, but we have some lower bounds.

From the latest series (emphasis mine):

> DOCTOR: Proposition. Davros is an insane, paranoid genius who has survived among several billion trigger-happy mini-tanks **for centuries**. Conclusion? I'm definitely having his chair.
>
> <sub>-- Series 9 Episode 2: *The Witch's Familiar*</sub>

That means Davros at least has lived for centuries. As for the Daleks, we have a lower bound of well over 50 years from an episode in the first series of New Who (emphasis mine):

> DOCTOR: A nightmare. It's a mutation. The Dalek race was genetically engineered. Every single emotion was removed except hate.
>   VAN STATTEN: Genetically engineered. By whom?
>   DOCTOR: By a genius, Van Statten. By a man who was king of his own little world. You'd like him.
>   GODDARD: **It's been on Earth for over fifty years.** Sold at a private auction, moving from one collection to another. Why would it be a threat now?
>
> <sub>-- Series 1 Episode 6, *Dalek*</sub>

Other than these lower bounds, we don't really know. The question [was posed on another site](http://doctorwho.answers.wikia.com/wiki/How_long_do_Daleks_live_naturally) and got the following answer:

> It is currently unknown but quite possibly forever.